# Add Column of Position of Column in Comma-Separated Other Column

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I have ugly data that looks like this:

```
source_data <- data.frame(thing = c('C', 'E', 'G'), ugly_sequence_string = c('A,B,C', 'D,E,F', 'G,H,I'))
```

I would like to add a column with the integer position of thing in ugly_sequence_string:

```
target_data <- data.frame(thing = c('C', 'E', 'G'), position = c(3L, 2L, 1L))
```

I feel like this has to be possible with some combination of strsplit (or stringr::str_split), dplyr::mutate, which, and maybe purrr::map, but I'm failing to wrap my mind around some aspect of how to do it. For example, this definitely doesn't work:

```
source_data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    position = which(stringr::str_split(ugly_sequence_string, ',') == thing)
  )
```

I've tried breaking that off into a function (with various combinations of unlist() and as.list() to get it into a format for which to be happy with), but it seems like this might be an easy thing that I'm just not grokking. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
source_data$index <- sapply(1:nrow(source_data), function(x) {which(
       strsplit(source_data$ugly_sequence_string[x],',')[[1]]==source_data$thing[x])})
```

Output:

```
  thing ugly_sequence_string index
1     C                A,B,C     3
2     E                D,E,F     2
3     G                G,H,I     1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get an error when I use strsplit: Error in strsplit(source_data$ugly_sequence_string[x], ",") : 
  non-character argument 

But it works when I switch to stringr::str_split, so that'll do! That's what I get for forgetting to go back to base R when it makes sense :)

Comment: Hi @Jon, might be that your column is of class factor instead of class character. `strsplit` takes a character vector, while `str_split` takes "either a character vector, or something coercible to one." Anway, glad your issue is resolved!

Comment: Ah, yup, that was the problem. I didn't pay attention when making my test data, since it isn't quite exactly the same as my real data of course.. but my real data has integers, so it's good to realize the difference!

Comment: Sorry mate. My answer is in similar lines of yours. I realized after posting.

Comment: No problem, nice solution too ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way could be using base `r` and `stringr` and `mapply` as:

```
source_data <- data.frame(thing = c('C', 'E', 'G'), 
                 ugly_sequence_string = c('A,B,C', 'D,E,F', 'G,H,I'))

library(stringr)
#Function to perform search
find_thing <- function(x, y){
  which(stringr::str_split(x, ',') [[1]] == y)
}

source_data$position <- mapply(find_thing, 
                               source_data$ugly_sequence_string, source_data$thing)

Result:
> source_data
  thing ugly_sequence_string position
1     C                A,B,C        3
2     E                D,E,F        2
3     G                G,H,I        1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(d,here=mapply(function(x,y)regexpr(x,gsub(",","",y))[[1]],d$thing,d$ugl))
  thing ugly_sequence_string here
C     C                A,B,C    3
E     E                D,E,F    2
G     G                G,H,I    1
```

or even:

```
 here=mapply(function(x,y)match(x,strsplit(y,",")[[1]]),d[,1],d[,2])
```

Comment: I'm not looking to split ugly_sequence string, I need an integer that tells me the position of thing in ugly_sequence_string.